# Testing GWT requestbuilder

Tags: java, gwt, testing, servlets, junit

I have following problem:

I have RequestBuilder, which calls http proxy servlet like [this one](https://github.com/dsmiley/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet/blob/master/src/main/java/org/mitre/dsmiley/httpproxy/ProxyServlet.java).

Now I try to test it.

I set up gwt maven plugin to use htmlunit. But when I launch my test requestbuilder request returns status code 404 (which, obviously, means "not found").

I have 2 ideas about it:

1) Servlet doesn't start up
2) Servlet starts up, but mapping doesn't work

Meanwhile same test works in IDE.

I do not have any idea how to diagnose this problem and what to do with whole this thing...

Answer (score 0):

Might be your problem with request url in RequestBuilder. it should be something like

`RequestBuilder builder=new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET,    GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()+"filename");`

Use **GWT.getHostPageBaseURL()**, instead of other manually stuff.

Comment: Thank you for idea, I've simplified my code a bit, but that didn't help. I still get 404 when run test with maven, but is succeeds from IDE...